# How to find the opauth config security_salt?

Tags: php, codeigniter, social-networking, opauth

I working on Codeigniter project for sign up with social logging. Here i use `opauth` third party. In that `security_salt` say `Your_salt` how to find the `your_salt`.

Please refer some reference for sign up with social media to the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can write anything there. It's a secure string created by you to salt the keys. So go with a random string.

Comment: @vigneshrajkumar I don't know exactly for what this library use this salt. But in general it's used to encrypt something, for example passwords. You can get a random string to use from here: http://randomkeygen.com/ if it's more easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Goto**

```
application/config/ci_opauth.php
```

**Change**

```
$config['opauth_config'] = array(
    'security_salt' => 'your_salt', # here
```

**What to change**

Can replace with any word

[View this](https://github.com/destinomultimedia/ci_opauth/blob/master/application/config/ci_opauth.php#L7)